# how can i get rid of duplication in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have $(this).css() a lot in my code...im new to JS so I'm not sure what the best way to remove this duplication and make my code clean...

here is the link to my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/7Y2Qp/

```
  $(".btn-pvPanels").on('click', function(event) {
  var selected;
  selected = $(this).val();
  if(selected === "on-panel") {
  $(this).css({
    'background': 'orange', 
    'color': 'white'
  });
  $(this).parent().find('.btn-off').css({
    'background': '#F1F1F1', 
    'color': '#8E8D8D'
  });
  $('.aon_poff').fadeIn('slow');
  } 

else if(selected === "off-panel")  {
  $(this).css({
    'background': 'orange', 
    'color': 'white'
  });
  $(this).parent().find('.btn-on').css({
    'background': '#F1F1F1', 
    'color': '#8E8D8D'
  });
  $('.aon_poff').fadeOut('slow');
  }

else if(selected === "on-accessories")  {
  $(this).css({
    'background': 'orange', 
    'color': 'white'
  });
  $(this).parent().find('.btn-on').css({
    'background': '#F1F1F1', 
    'color': '#8E8D8D'
  });

  }

else if(selected === "on-accessories" && "on-panel")  {
  $(this).css({
    'background': 'orange', 
    'color': 'white'
  });
  $(this).parent().find('.btn-on').css({
    'background': '#F1F1F1', 
    'color': '#8E8D8D'
  });
     alert('hey')
  }

});


   $(".btn-accessories").on('click', function(event) {
var selected;
selected = $(this).val();
if(selected === "on-accessories") {
  $(this).css({
    'background': 'orange', 
    'color': 'white'
  });
  $(this).parent().find('.btn-off').css({
    'background': '#F1F1F1', 
    'color': '#8E8D8D'
  });
  $('.aoff_pon').fadeIn('slow');
  } 

else if(selected === "off-accessories")  {
  $(this).css({
    'background': 'orange', 
    'color': 'white'
  });
  $(this).parent().find('.btn-on').css({
    'background': '#F1F1F1', 
    'color': '#8E8D8D'
  });
  $('.aoff_pon').fadeOut('slow');
  }



});
```

Comment: Simplest way is to move those properties into CSS classes and use addClass()/removeClass() where appropriate.

Comment: adding some or statements may help

Comment: Why do you assign the same CSS styles over and over? It doesn't seem to change anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS class names to style:

```
.selected { 
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
}
.deselected {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    color: #8E8D8D;
}
```

Now instead of setting `.css()` you can use:

`addClass('selected')` and `removeClass('selected')` for the orange background.

`addClass('deselected')` and `removeClasS('deselected')` for the grey background.

Comment: so when i click ON the color changes correctly but when I click OFF again the color does not change back http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/7Y2Qp/

Comment: @user1502223 You have to remove the `selected` class when you add the `deselected` class. Also, you have to be sure you aren't calling `.css()` anywhere, because the values you use in there will override the values in the CSS classes.

Comment: so heres my new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/7Y2Qp/ its looking much better but is there any way to remove even more duplication?

Comment: Here's a fiddle that's a bit better: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y2Qp/10/. I moved some common stuff into a function, and made it use jquery to select whichever button it's not (this only works for two buttons, however)

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid the inline styles you have in your html, and just use css to set those styles.